# Memory used greatly exceeds memory being used by running programs

Tags: memory

My running processes:
[image]

Any idea what might be using up the other bit of RAM?
Clearly you can see by adding up the memory used by the processes it exceeds the apparent 5124MB being used.

Comment: post pictures of RAMMap which breaks down the usage in a more detailed way: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system alone takes up quite a bit of memory, looking at your processes it looks pretty in check to me, so that's what's most likely causing your usage. Was this a problem in the past or just recent ?

Comment: It has always been a problem but I am looking into it now because I need the extra RAM. Would my OS be taking up the whole (5124mb - total of what the processes use)?

Comment: Yeah, i have 8 gb installed on my computer and its pretty normal to see 2-3 gb available when doing everyday tasks. Upgrading is always a solution!

Comment: What  exactly does Windows use it for? Any way to reduce that?

Comment: Windows uses a chunk of your ram just to perform standard tasks essential to keeping the OS running smooth and stable, im not sure EXACTLY what it uses it for but im sure other SU members would be aware but its kinda irrelevant. You can try ending the processes yourself or theres some good software out there to help you aswell! Hopefully this helps

Comment: If I could see the processes that were using the remainder of my RAM, I'd close them :-)